Is there a way to solve the Vehicle Routing Problem (VRP) using ComputeRoutes API?
I want to solve the issue of the Vehicle Routing Problem (VRP) using ComputeRoutes google API (API), as it is more clear and supports nodejs.
I have already create the function with ComputeRoutes, the issue is that I can only create the best route for one vehicle, but what if I need multiple vehicles to complete the destinations?
It is possible?
Part of the Code:
const data = {
        origin: locationOrigin,
        destination: locationOrigin,
        intermediates: [] as WayPoint[],
        travelMode: "DRIVE",
        routingPreference: "TRAFFIC_AWARE",
        computeAlternativeRoutes: false,
        optimizeWaypointOrder: true,
      };

      way = {} as Way;
      orders.forEach((order: any) => {
        const waypoint = {
          placeId: order.order.address.placeId,
        };
        intermediates.push(waypoint);
      });

      data.intermediates = intermediates;

      console.log("data ", data);

      await doRequest(data, "routes")
        .then((data: any) => {
          console.log("yeei ", data);
          console.log(
            "optimizedIntermediateWaypointIndex ",
            data.routes.optimizedIntermediateWaypointIndex
          );
          way = createWaysWithWaypoints(
            data.routes[0],
            orders,
            riders[0],
            data.routes[0].optimizedIntermediateWaypointIndex,
            wayscount
          );
          ways.push(way);
          //wayscount ++;
          console.log("ways ", ways);
        })
        .catch((error: any) => {
          errorMessage = error;
          // Log the error message and code
          console.log(`Error message: ${error.message}`);
          console.log(`Error code: ${error.code}`);

          // Log the response status and data if available
          if (error.response) {
            console.log(`Response status: ${error.response.status}`);
            console.log(
              `Response data: ${JSON.stringify(error.response.data)}`
            );
          }

          // Log the request method and path if available
          if (error.request) {
            console.log(`Request method: ${error.request.method}`);
            console.log(`Request path: ${error.request.path}`);
          }

          return {
            statusCode: 400,
            headers: {
              "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "*",
              "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
              "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "*",
            },
            body: JSON.stringify(error.message),
          };
        });

doRequest function:
function doRequest(data: any, opt: string) {
  let result = "";
  return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
   
  


      var options = {
        host: "routes.googleapis.com",
        path: "/directions/v2:computeRoutes",
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
          "X-Goog-Api-Key": "xyz",
          "X-Goog-FieldMask":
            "routes.optimizedIntermediateWaypointIndex,routes.duration,routes.distanceMeters,routes.polyline.encodedPolyline,routes.routeLabels,routes.legs.distanceMeters,routes.legs.duration",
        },
      };


    let post_req = http.request(options, function (res: any) {
      //res.setEncoding('utf8');
      let body = "";
      res.on("data", function (chunk: any) {
        body += chunk;
        console.log("Response: ", body);
      });

      res.on("end", () => {
        console.log("body ", JSON.parse(body));

        resolve(JSON.parse(body));
      });

      res.on("error", function (e: any) {
        console.log("Got error: " + e.message);
      });
    });
    post_req.write(JSON.stringify(data));
    post_req.end();
  });
}


For multiple vehicles you can use the Route Optimization API:

The Route Optimization API assigns tasks and routes to a vehicle fleet, optimizing against the objectives and constraints that you supply for your transportation goals.

